# find a cochain map $ψ: A• → B•$ with a condition that $ψ^i:A^i→B^i$ is an inijective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, de-rham-cohomology

I try to find an example for a cochain map $ψ: A• → B•$ that exists : 
$ψ^i:A^i→B^i$ is an injective map (for i>=0) but
 $ψ∗ :H^k(A∙)→H^k(B∙)$ is not a injective map (for k>=0)?
I use the fact that a short exact sequences of cochain complexes induces a long exact sequence on the cohomology.
I will be happy if someone give me a hint.
thank you!

Comment: Change the title into something meaningful and I will help you.

Comment: @k.stm, thanks to you!

Comment: Zero maps are not bijective unless both sides are zeros. But in this case cohomologies are zeros as well and so the induced map is again bijective.

Comment: Also I assume your cochains have non-trivial negative elements? Because otherwise your $\psi$ is simply a cochain isomorphism (and so induces isomorphisms on cohomologies).

Comment: @freakish,do you mean that the cochain that I look for must be surjective also ?

Comment: @Sila bijective = injective + surjective. It's a property of functions, not cochains. Unless by "cochain" you mean "cochain map"? Are we talking about [abstract cochain complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex)?

Comment: ah! I consider that the word bijective meaning is not  injective + surjective.

Comment: @freakish, now I want a cochain map that is only injective (one to one function)

Comment: @Sila ok, so you want a cochain map that is injective **but** homology map that is not injective? Please update the question.

Comment: @freakish, the question is written in another language.

Comment: Where do your cochain complexes start, Sila? Do they start at zero, so like $A^0 → A^1 → A^2 → …$, or are they infinite in both directios, like $… → A^{-2} → A^{-1} → A^0 → A^1 → A^2 →…$?

Comment: @k.stm, cochain complexes start az zero because $(i>=0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^•$ be the cochain complex
$$0 → ℤ → ℤ → ℤ → …,$$
where every horizontal map is trivial, and $B^•$ be the cochain complex
$$0 \oplus ℤ → ℤ\oplus ℤ → ℤ \oplus ℤ → ℤ\oplus ℤ → …,$$
wherey every horizontal map projects the right component onto the left component.

Can you construct a cochain map $ψ^• \colon A^• → B^•$ yourself that is injective, but doesn’t induce an injective map $ψ^•_\ast$ on the cohomologies?

Comment: yes I can, thank you very much!

Comment: what is  "Z"  called in  english?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: Doesn't the question say that $\psi^k$ should not be injective **for any $k$**?

Comment: @freakish Oh, right, … I now have updated my answer.